# Concat in where clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query that uses concat and replace in the where clause:

```
select * from table1 where name in
(concat("'",(REPLACE('name1,name2,name3', ',', "','")),"'"));
```

This query doesn't work. Could you please help me in identifing the issue?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and what doesn't work? Are you trying to build a set dynamically and match `name` against it?

Comment: Give us more info about the error you get.

Comment: From the string 'name1,name2,name3', I want the individual strings as 'name1','name2','name3' so that i could use them in the above query.

Comment: your concat returns a single String. You need to split this string a the `,`. I think there is no build in sql function for this.

Comment: please update the question add and some data along with table with the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to replace the single quotes around the name1..:

```
select * 
from table1 
where `name` in (concat("'",(REPLACE("name1,name2,name3", ",", "','")),"'"));
```

Comment: I tested that in MySQL.  The only difference was the table name and col.  Try and put " ` " (accent) before and after "Name".  It could be a reserved word.